# minimum cost for string transformation

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given two string A and B. We want to transform A to B. There are two ways to do this:

1. Delete `N consecutive` characters at a cost of 2 per operation;
2. Add `N consecutive` characters (any characters you need), at a cost of `N+2` (each operation).

What is the minimum cost for transforming A to B? 
for example,

**Input**

A: `dsafsadfadf`

B: `fdfd`

**Output**

7

**Hint:**

1. `dsafsadfadf` -> `f`, delete 10 consecutive characters, cost=2
2. `f` -> `fdfd` add 3 consecutive characters (`dfd`), cost=3+2=5

The minimum cost=2+5=7, which is smaller than any other transformation cost.

Similarly, `aaaaaaaa` -> `bbbbbbbb`, minimum cost=2+10=12

You can use these two ways in multiple times, not confined to 2 times.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the requirements. Do you have any problems with your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one recursive direction you might choose to work with. Let `f(i,j,n)` represent the cost of the changes made up to index `i` of string `A`, so the current prefix matches string `B` up to index `j` and the previous change is recorded in `n`: if `n` equals `-1`, the last move was a deletion; if `n` is zero, no characters were added or deleted in the previous move; if `n` is positive, the `nth` consecutive character was added in the last move. Complexity `O(|A| * |B|^2)`.

Then:

```
var A = "dsafsadfadf",
    B = "fdfd";

function f(i,j,n){ 
  // base case end of A and B
  if (i == A.length && j == B.length){
    return 2 + (n > 0 ? n : 0);
  }  

  // base case end of A:
  if (i == A.length){
    var to_add = B.length - j;
    return 2 + to_add + (n > 0 ? n : 0) + (n < 0 ? 2 : 0);
  }   

  // base case end of B
  if (j == B.length){
    if (n <= 0){
      return 2;
    } else {
      return 4 + n;
    }
  } 

  // otherwise if there's a match
  var use_match = Infinity;

  if (A[i] == B[j]){
    prev_cost = (n != 0 ? 2 : 0) + (n > 0 ? n : 0);
    use_match = prev_cost + f(i + 1,j + 1,0);
  }

  // use or do not use the match
  var delete_char, add_char;

  if (n < 0){
    delete_char = f(i + 1,j,-1);
    add_char = 2 + f(i,j + 1,1);

  } else if (n > 0){
    delete_char = 2 + n + f(i + 1,j,-1);
    add_char = f(i,j + 1,n + 1);

  } else {
    delete_char = f(i + 1,j,-1);
    add_char = f(i,j + 1,1);
  }

  return Math.min(use_match,Math.min(delete_char,add_char));
}

console.log(f(0,0,0));
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a variation of the classic Edit Distance (Levenhstein Distance) problem, and can be solved by a similar dynamic programming approach.

Let the function be `f (x, y)` = minimum cost to transform first `x` characters of `A` into first `y` characters of `B`. Consider a solution which led to this value of `f`. What could be the possible last operation?

It could be deleting some characters from the suffix of the first argument, so `f (x, y)` could be `f (u, y) + 2` for all `u` from `0` to `x`, inclusive.

It could also be adding some characters to the suffix of the second argument, so `f (x, y)` could be `f (x, v) + 2 + (y - v)` for all `v` from `0` to `y`, inclusive.

Now, take the minimum of the `x + y + 2` options listed above, and you get the value of `f (x, y)`.

The base case is `f (0, 0) = 0`.
The answer is the value of `f (|A|, |B|)`.

The total complexity is something like O (|A| * |B| * (|A| + |B|)).